# MATLAB: Remove duplicate lat/lon points and corresponding data point from matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I have a matrix of latitudes, a matrix of longitudes, and a matrix of measurements at these lat/lon points.

Some lat/lon points have multiple measurements. I'd like a way to remove the duplicate measurements from the matrices, keeping only the larger measurement.

So with the data:

```
lat  = [0,1,2,3,1,2]
lon  = [0,1,2,3,1,4]
data = [5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

The data point at (1,1) with a measurement of 6 would be removed, resulting in:
    lat  = [0,2,3,1,2]
    lon  = [0,2,3,1,4]
    data = [5,7,8,9,10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'rows'` option on a matrix where the columns are the `lat` and `lon` variables. This will provide you with the unique `lat` and `lon` combinations *and* it provides you with an index (the third output) which can be passed to [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to return the maximum value in `data` for each unique combination of `lat` and `lon`.

```
% Find the unique combinations of latitude and longitude
[latlon, ~, inds] = unique([lat(:), lon(:)], 'rows', 'stable');

% Find the maximum value in data for each unique lat/lon combo
maxdata = accumarray(inds, data(:), [], @max);
%   5   9   7   8   10

% Expand out latlon variable if needed
latitude = latlon(:,1);
%   0   1   2   3   2

longitude = latlon(:,2);
%   0   1   2   3   4
```

If you need the latitude and longitude ordered by the `data` value (as you've shown in your question):

```
[maxdata, ind] = sort(maxdata);
%   5   7   8   9   10

latitude = latlon(ind,1);
%   0   2   3   1   2

longitude = latlon(ind,2);
%   0   2   3   1   4
```